# Is there any way to use global like values in a nodejs app?

Tags: node.js, express, backend

I have this simple expressjs app that serve some data but this data are actualy less than 10 values so use a database seems like an overkill but to generete this values is a heavy process so what i have in mind is to run the process to generete the values when the app start and then serve this values in the app endpoints. Is there any way to keep this values consistenly without having to run the process of generarte the values from scratch?. I know that nodejs have a "global" values feature but i have reed that is not recommended to use it so i have been looking for an alternative any advise?

Comment: You could use some file system, update your values in the file every time and read the file on API request.

Comment: You can use a module-level variable (declared outside your routes, but in the same module) very easily as long as you want the same data available to all requests, not just requests from one particular user.  Show us your actual code and we can advise more specifically.  Or, you can put the data in its own module, initialize it upon startup and export it so any module that wants access to it, can just import the module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a JSON file and add values to it, then `require` it and save it to a variable:

```
// example.json
{
  "example": "I am an example!"
}
```

```
// server.js
const exampleData = require('./example.json');
console.log(exampleData.example) // Output: "I am an example!"
```